# How do I separately render various items in a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
        "id": "abc",
        "title": "Title1",
        "cover": "https://example.tld/pic0.jpg",
        "pictures": [
            "https://example.tld/pic1.jpg",
            "https://example.tld/pic2.jpg",
            "https://example.tld/pic3.jpg",
            "https://example.tld/pic4.jpg",
            "https://example.tld/pic5.jpg"
        ],
        "description": "Lorem ipsum...",
        "host": {
            "name": "John Appleseed",
            "picture": "https://example.tld/pic6.jpg"
        },
        "rating": "5",
        "location": "Paris",
        "equipments": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
        ],
        "tags": [
            "Tag1",
            "Tag2"
        ]
    },
```

Below this array there are many more, with the exact same structure.

In React I'm trying to render every image separately, and each tag in its own `<li>`.
To do this I've created an element:

```
export const HousingPage = ({pictures, title, location, host, hostpic, tags, desctext, equiptext}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={pictures}/>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <p>{location}</p>
            <p>{host}</p>
            <img src={hostpic} />
            <li>{tags}</li>
            <div>
                <h2>Description</h2>
                <p>{desctext}</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Équipements</h2>
                <p>{equiptext}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Then imported the JSON in App.js with `const data = require("../datas/logements.json")` and added the element:

```
<HousingPage pictures={housing.pictures} location={housing.location title={housing.title} ... />
```

However the tags render as a single line, and the single picture that's rendered has a string with every single image URL as the src.
How do I select, for example, all the pictures in an array that has the id "abc" and render them separately? Same question for the tags.

Comment: `pictures.map(...)`? It's not clear how you _want_ them to be rendered, and this is a very basic task in React: https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
<img src={pictures}/>
```

Is trying to use *an array* as the value for `src`.  The `src` needs to just be a single URL.  To display multiple images, use multiple `<img>` elements.  For example:

```
{ pictures.map((p, i) => <img key={i} src={p}/>) }
```

Comment: But how do I select all the pictures that correspond to the same ID?

Comment: @8bitmd: That depends on what you even mean by that.  The `pictures` property in the data shown is just an array of string values (URLs).  If you want to show only a subset of those pictures, you'll first need to define how you determine which ones to show.  It's not really clear what you're trying to ask, and it may merit a separate Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can render images using img tag like this:

```
{pictures.map((picture, index) => <img key={index} src={p}> )}
```

I put key attribute because React needs index to various elements rendered
So your final code looks like this:

```
export const HousingPage = ({pictures, title, location, host, hostpic, tags, desctext, equiptext}) => {
return (
    <div>
        {pictures.map((picture, index) => <img key={index} src={p}> )}
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <p>{location}</p>
        <p>{host}</p>
        <img src={hostpic} />
        <li>{tags}</li>
        <div>
            <h2>Description</h2>
            <p>{desctext}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Équipements</h2>
            <p>{equiptext}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
)}
```

You can increase your view with card or carrousel or other list your image.
I hope help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the props "pictures" passed to HousingPage component, inside the component. You can modify your HousingPage component as below.

```
function HousingPage(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.pictures && props.pictures.map((picture, index) => (
                <img key={index} src={picture} />
            ))}

            <h1>{props.title}</h1>
            <p>{props.location}</p>
            <p>{props.host}</p>
            <img src={props.hostpic} crossOrigin="anonymous" />
            <li>{props.tags}</li>
            <div>
                <h2>Description</h2>
                <p>{props.desctext}</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Équipements</h2>
                <p>{props.equiptext}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default HousingPage;
```